how to hide the X at the top of the shadcn dialog box?
The shadcn/ui dialog box by default as a X at the top right hand corner.  My design does not have the X.  How to hide the X while retaining the esc to close functionality ?
Thanks very much.


in your component/ui/dialog, comment out this:
<DialogPrimitive.Close className="...">
  <X className="h-4 w-4" />
  <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
</DialogPrimitive.Close>


I manage to remove this.  Just wondering if I update Shadcn, then it will be replace, right ?  Any specific solution to make this permanent for this project ?

If you don't want to edit the Dialog component directly, you can add this class to DialogContent:
<DialogContent className="[&>button]:hidden">

This way the close button will be hidden.

Instant solution. Worked for me.

Instead of completely hiding the close functionality of the dialog as mentioned in the accepted answer, we can just pass a prop to handle this customized functionality:
Passing custom prop 'hideClose' to hide the close functionality
<DialogContent hideClose className="bg-transparent border-none" />

Inside the dialog ui component, we can accept that custom prop like this:
const DialogContent = React.forwardRef<
React.ElementRef<typeof DialogPrimitive.Content>,
React.ComponentPropsWithoutRef<typeof DialogPrimitive.Content> & 
{
    hideClose?: boolean;
}
>(({ className, children, hideClose, ...props }, ref) => (
<DialogPortal>
   {!hideClose && } //use the prop
</DialogPortal>


You can add a prop to show/hide close button on DialogContent component.
This way you get control over when to show and hide the close button.
const DialogContent = React.forwardRef(
  ({className, children, ...props}, ref) => (
    <DialogPortal>
      <DialogOverlay />
      <DialogPrimitive.Content
        ref={ref}
        className={cn(
          'fixed left-[50%] top-[50%] z-50 grid w-full max-w-lg translate-x-[-50%] translate-y-[-50%] gap-4 border bg-background p-6 shadow-lg duration-200 data-[state=open]:animate-in data-[state=closed]:animate-out data-[state=closed]:fade-out-0 data-[state=open]:fade-in-0 data-[state=closed]:zoom-out-95 data-[state=open]:zoom-in-95 data-[state=closed]:slide-out-to-left-1/2 data-[state=closed]:slide-out-to-top-[48%] data-[state=open]:slide-in-from-left-1/2 data-[state=open]:slide-in-from-top-[48%] sm:rounded-lg',
          className,
        )}
        {...props}
      >
        {children}
        {!props.hideClose && (
          <DialogPrimitive.Close className="absolute right-4 top-4 rounded-sm opacity-70 ring-offset-background transition-opacity hover:opacity-100 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-ring focus:ring-offset-2 disabled:pointer-events-none data-[state=open]:bg-accent data-[state=open]:text-muted-foreground">
            <X className="h-4 w-4" />
            <span className="sr-only">Close</span>
          </DialogPrimitive.Close>
        )}
      </DialogPrimitive.Content>
    </DialogPortal>
  ),
);


The current accepted answer ( and also the most upvoted) has problems depending on how you wish to implement the dialog close button.
The most upvoted answer:

<DialogContent className="[&>button]:hidden">


has some problems:

hides any other button element added directly inside the DialogContent as child.

the current accepted answer's approach gets overriden when you update shadcn ui.


This new solution:

<DialogContent className="[&>button:last-child]:hidden">



doesn't need you to remove <DialogPrimitive.Close> used by shadcn.

you can use the <DialogClose> or nest any <button> inside the <DialogContent> without worrying about it being hidden by [&>button]:hidden.



<DialogContent hideClose>

you can add a hideClose prop to the dialogcontent like this.
